# jQuery ajax parameter value pulled dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Wondering if there is someway to do this without using a timeout.

Right now I have an ajax request that pulls in a token via an external js. I don't have full control over this script as its provided by a 3rd party.

So it basically does an ajax request and passes me back a token vaule. I then take that value and update a form input with it.

My problem is the form submits before it has time to fully get value, hence the value is never passed.

I have some responses to work with that this 3rd party script provides, right now I am doing something like.

resonseData is passed back to me from this script..

```
  if(responseData.dataValue !='') {
            $('[name=payment_token]').val(responseData.dataValue, function(){
                $("#userPaymentUpdate").submit();

            });
        }
```

^ The problem is the form submits before it has time to update the $('[name=payment_token]').val()

Is there anyway way round this aside for putting a timeout in? I thought by adding a callback like above would solve it, but apparently it doesn't.

I also have event.preventDefault(); on the form click handler, but when thats enable the 3rd party script wont execute at all.  So basically need to only submit the form if that payment_token value has been updated.

Comment: Show the full context of this code. We don't know how it fits into the form processing or where you are calling the ajax  from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, it looks more like an issue of order. responseData.dataValue has the value, otherwise that if condition wouldn't have processed.

Your code should look something like this:

```
if(responseData.dataValue !='') {
        $('input[name=payment_token]').val(responseData.dataValue); /* I'm guessing you're using a hidden field for the payment token. */
        $("#userPaymentUpdate").submit(); /* at this point, the value will have already been assigned. */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. how I missed that.  Was thinking I needed a callback for it.